# convert table to div as per bootstrap v4 beta

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap v4 beta. I have created a table. How can i create the same table using div.

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th class="text-center"><b>Id</b></th>
        <th class="text-center"><b>Name</b></th>
        <th class="text-center"><b>Munit</b></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> 1</td>
        <td class="text-center"> 294</td>
        <td class="text-center"> nimai</td>
        <td class="text-center"> kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 2</td>
        <td class="text-center"> 200</td>
        <td class="text-center"> nitai</td>
        <td class="text-center"> kg</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I also want the same format it looks like in the below picture:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to? This looks like tabular data. Therefore a `<table>` is semantically correct.

Comment: The problem is i am going to add forms inside this table to edit the data inline or a drop down in reactjs. The forms are not properly getting added. Sometime they jump to the end. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619308/reactjs-how-to-create-table-with-editable-rows-and-post-data-and-show-validatio

Comment: Im not sure you should compromise the semantics to "make it work".

Comment: i also want to keep it as table only. but the form keeps jumping out of the table

Answer (score 2):

You can make that easily using `flexbox`

```css
.table {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vw;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table-header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.table-row div:first-child {
  width: 10% !important;
}

.table-row-column {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row table-header">
      <div class="table-row-column table-row-index">#</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">Id</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">Name</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">Munit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-row-column table-row-index">1</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">294</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">nimai</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">kg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-row-column table-row-index">2</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">200</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">nitai</div>
      <div class="table-row-column table-center">kg</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show using Display property .d-table etc from bootstrap v4

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.col {
display: inline-block;
}

row {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
     <div>First column</div>
     <div> 1</div>
     <div> 2</div>
      <div>3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div>Second column</div>
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
   </div>
   
      <div class="col">
     <div>Third column</div>
     <div>1</div>
     <div>2</div>
     <div>3</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: But here we are mixing the table label.

Comment: change `row{` to `.row{` only